# How to wrap text around an image using CSS

Tags: css, html, word-wrap

I am looking to wrap text around an image that will lie in the bottom left hand corner of a CSS table. The amount of text changes when I use it because I will be using it numerous times with different amounts of text in it. I am wondering if this is possible and if so, how I can accomplish this?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know what a "CSS table" is. In general, this is accomplished by "float"ing the picture.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I got really confused with your question, maybe this answer has nothing to do with your question, please tell me if so, but this is the closest I could think of a css table that adjusts the height when the "amount of text changes" I not sure where the image came in.

http://www.jsfiddle.net/5m5Eh/

Good luck! hope it helps!